# Ajax Load Function not working on postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am having an issue with loading a page with Ajax on postback.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GridView").load("/MyInnerPage.aspx");
    });

</script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="AccountName"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Search" runat="server" Text="Search" />

<div id="GridView">
</div>
```

The eventual idea behind is is that the user enters text into the AccountName text box, and when they submit it the page does a postback, and determines the search parameters from the code behind.  Eventually the page that is loaded (ie '/MyInnerPage') will have a dynamic set of arguments passed to it, depending on the search parameters.  That is outside the scope of this issue though.

As an overview, when you first visit the page, it works perfectly.  The contents of 'MyInnerPage.aspx' is loaded into the 'GridView' div.

However the problem occurs as soon as you hit 'search'.  The page does a postback, and immediately the contents of the 'GridView' div is lost.  However for some reason the line:

```
$("#GridView").load("/MyInnerPage.aspx");
```

is no longer firing properly.  I know that the line is being run, since I can put an alert statement before it, which is displayed on the screen.  However, no matter what I can do, I cannot seem to get 'MyInnerPage' displaying in the div after the first postback.  It just displays as an empty div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your doing a full postback or not. Check this post out

http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2009/02/24/jQuery-document-ready-and-ASP-NET-Ajax-asynchronous-postback.aspx